# How to Python @overload a @staticmethod

Tags: python

I am trying to overload a staticmethod in python, and it is not working as expected the staticmethod overwrites the instance method and throws `TypeError`, see code. Is it possible to achieve this? if so how?

```
from typing import overload

class A:
    
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    @overload
    def my_print(self):
        A.my_print(self.text)

    @staticmethod
    def my_print(text):
        print (text)

a = A("test") 
a.my_print() # (<class 'TypeError'>, A.my_print() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text' ...
a.my_print('test2') # calls staticmethod through instance

A.my_print('test3')
```

Currently the workaround I am using is to rename one of the function and without the @overload

Comment: What's your real world use case? It doesn't make much sense to have this kind of static methods, not to mention that `@overload` are for type hinting only.

Comment: i know it is a simplified example, currently the workaround I am using is to rename one of the function, which is not using overloading

Comment: An `@overload` method shouldn't have a body, since it never actually gets called - it's merely a way to declare an alternate form of the parameter list that the actual definition also supports.

Comment: I am coming from a Java/C# background and maybe @overload isn't same as I expected.

Comment: @Ash No, it isn't. In those languages, overloading is for executing different code depending on the argument types. In Python it's just for telling static type checkers that the function can be called with different argument types (when called with type A, it returns type B). You execute different code using conditionals in the actual implementation function.